# Using Sardines report method to query events from CalDAV server

Tags: caldav, sardine, biweekly

I'm trying to fetch events from a CalDAV server using [Sardine](https://github.com/lookfirst/sardine) (and [biweekly](https://github.com/mangstadt/biweekly)). Fetching an entire calendar is working for me:

```
Sardine sardine = SardineFactory.begin();
InputStream is = sardine.get(CALDAV_URL_STRING);
ICalendar iCalendar = Biweekly.parse(is).first();
```

Now I would like to fetch events for specific time range. Based on this "[Building a CalDAV client](http://sabre.io/dav/building-a-caldav-client/)" article, I assume you should use Sardines [`report`](https://github.com/lookfirst/sardine/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/sardine/Sardine.java#L112) method to do so, right?

If so, how should you use that method? It's not documented in the wiki, and the Javadoc is also not very clear.

Should I write my own [`SardineReport`](https://github.com/lookfirst/sardine/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/sardine/report/SardineReport.java)? I looks like I should end up with something like:

```
Sardine sardine = SardineFactory.begin();
SardineReport<List<VEvent>> report = new MyRangeReport(FROM_DATE, END_DATE);
List<VEvent> result = sardine.report(CALDAV_URL_STRING, 1, report);
```

Am I on the right track? Does anyone have any pointers to how to write your own Sardine report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, to run a time range query you need to issue an HTTP `REPORT` request containing a `calendar-query`. You can find a sample in [RFC 4719 Section 7.8.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791#section-7.8.1). I don't know Sardine, but yes, `report` sounds right ;-)

Simplified even further:

```
 REPORT /bernard/work/ HTTP/1.1
 Host: cal.example.com
 Depth: 1
 Content-Type: application/xml; charset="utf-8"
 Content-Length: xxxx

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <calendar-query xmlns:D="DAV:" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav">
   <D:prop>
     <D:getetag/>
     <calendar-data />
   </D:prop>
   <filter>
     <comp-filter name="VCALENDAR">
       <comp-filter name="VEVENT">
         <time-range start="20060104T000000Z" end="20060105T000000Z"/>
       </comp-filter>
     </comp-filter>
  </filter>
</calendar-query>
```

> Should I write my own SardineReport?

Looks like, scanning over the GitHub of Sardine it doesn't seem to include CalDAV queries. You can probably base yours on their
[SyncCollectionReport.java](https://github.com/lookfirst/sardine/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/sardine/report/SyncCollectionReport.java).

Note that the response to the `calendar-query` `REPORT` is just a regular WebDAV `207` `multi-status` response. Nothing extra required. (the `Result` object would be the same like in their `SyncCollectionReport` but w/o the extra syncToken).

Comment: Thanks! I already wrote my own report class which returns results. I'm starting to wonder if Radicale (server we're using) supports the `time-range` filter.

Comment: I don't know, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711699/expanding-recurring-events-in-caldav) suggests it doesn't. Check the comment: "The problem lies with Radicale. Switched to SabreDAV, now it works"

Comment: Thanks. I think we need to check out sabre/dav. For documentation sake I've added my report class.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a report class which works, however, the result returned by Radicale seem to be incorrect. It looks like Radicale does not support the `time-range` filter.

For what it's worth, here are the relevant bits of the report:

```
public class VEventsTimeRangeSardineReport extends SardineReport<List<VEvent>>
{

    ...

    @Override
    public String toXml() throws IOException
    {
        // Hardcode for now
        String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>\n" +
                     "<c:calendar-query xmlns:d=\"DAV:\" xmlns:c=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav\">\n" +
                     "  <d:prop>\n" +
                     "    <c:calendar-data/>\n" +
                     "    <d:getetag/>\n" +
                     "  </d:prop>\n" +
                     "  <c:filter>\n" +
                     "    <c:comp-filter name=\"VCALENDAR\">\n" +
                     "      <c:comp-filter name=\"VEVENT\">\n" +
                     "        <c:time-range start=\"%s\" end=\"%s\"/>\n" +
                     "      </c:comp-filter>\n" +
                     "    </c:comp-filter>\n" +
                     "  </c:filter>\n" +
                     "</c:calendar-query>";
        return String.format(xml, SDF.format(fromDate), SDF.format(toDate));
    }


    @Override
    public List<VEvent> fromMultistatus(Multistatus multistatus)
    {
        List<VEvent> events = new ArrayList<>(multistatus.getResponse().size());
        for (Response response : multistatus.getResponse()) {
            // Here response.getPropstat().get(0).getProp().getAny().get(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent() is parsed
            events.addAll(ICalendarSardineReport.getICalendar(response).getEvents());
        }
        return events;
    }


    @Override
    public Object toJaxb()
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```