# Google Caldav API : issue with event rrule until?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, caldav

I just met a problem with the API of Google Caldav on a recurring event with an end date

For example, if I have reccuring event every day between 15h and 17h until 31/08/2016, the ical event indicated :

RRULE=FREQ=WEEKLY;**UNTIL=20160831T130000Z**;BYDAY=TU,WE,TH,FR,SA

it should not be more (end of event) : **UNTIL=20160831T150000Z** ?

Thanks for you help

Damien

Comment: Please check solution given in this related SO question - [Expanding recurring events in CalDAV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711699/expanding-recurring-events-in-caldav). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your recurring event goes from 15:00-17:00 in CET or a similar timezone. CET in summertime is UTC +2 hours, so this is correct:

```
UNTIL=20160831T130000Z
```

13:00 UTC is 15:00 CET. The `Z` suffix marks the `DATETIME` values as UTC (read [RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.5), "FORM #2: DATE WITH UTC TIME")

Answer (score 0):

The recurrence stuff always refers to the start of the instances. So `UNTIL` specifies the last permissible start date(-time) of an instance. The actual duration of the instances doesn't matter at all.

I think RFC 5545 doesn't state this explicitly, but I think it becomes clear if you read through all the sections about recurrence.